# find min number using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, min

How can I find minimum number using list comprehension?

This is the code I tried :

```
def qwe(some_list, min_num):
    b = float('inf')
    for i in some_list:
        if min_num < i < b:
            b = i
    print(b)
a = [2,3,5,8,5,6,3,2,4,5,8,9,6,3,1,7,5,4,1,2,5,6,3]
qwe(a,3)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "find this"?

Comment: a = [2,3,3,4,5,6,7,5,3,2,3,5]
ma = 10
mi = 3
q= [3]
qq = [b = i for i in a if mi<i<ma] !!!! Sorry for my english. I want to write code like this, but I have : SyntaxError: invalid syntax <string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find a minimum number you can use

```
min(my_list)
```

However, you are looking for the minimum number that is higher than `min_num`. Using list comprehension you can select all numbers larger than min_num as follows:

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if x > min_num]
```

By combining the two you will get your answer

```
min([x for x in my_list if x > min_num])
```

Comment: Is it possible to write: [max = i for i in list if min<i<max], dont use min(), because this variant I know

Comment: I believe that since python3.8 it is possible to do assignments within list comprehension by using the `:=` symbol. E.g. `[max := i for i in list if min < i < max]` However, I am not convinced it works for your scenario as I think list comprehension is performed by iterating over elements. E.g. if max is changed, it will not change elements that have already been visited. Furthermore you will be left with a list (possibly with a single element), whereas your problem statement seems to require the solution as a single number.

Answer (score 0):

## Using list comprehension,if..else, tested for multiple inputs

input

> if a[0] == each else a[0] this condition in list comprehension
>   validates the the each element is greater orless than a[0]

```
 a = [2,3,5,8,5,6,3,2,4,5,8,9,6,3,-3,-47,-5,-4,-1,-2,-5,-6,-3]

min_num = min([each if a[0] == each else a[0] for each in a ])
print(min_num)
```

## Using  function:

1. This function takes two arguments - list1 - the
2. input list of numbers and min is  variable set to None, this will be
   returned as output on finding the minimum number
3. Next line sorts the input list1 using sort()
4. For loop to iterate through each element and compare
   until we get a minimum number in the list
5. Since the list is sorted,take a[0] as min_number if an element in the list is greater than a[0]
6. assigning min value to a[0]

## function to find the minimum number

```
def min_num(list1, min = None): 

    list1.sort() 
    for each in list1:
        if a[0] == each: 
            min = each   
        elif a[0] < each: 
            min = a[0]
    return min
```

## Driver code

```
b = min_num(a,min = None)
print(b)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: Added additional information to understand the code